# ElasticSearchJSON Output to parquet File

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

i am reading ElasticSearch indices data as JSON and want to save this as parquet. below is the code:
'''
JavaPairRDD<String,String> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esJsonRDD(jsc, "companydatabase/employees");
'''

How can i convert JavaPairRDD<String,String> to dataset in Java. Output format will be like
C1
JSON1
JSON2

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esJsonRDD(jsc,esPath);
 Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(esRDD.collect(), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.STRING())).toDF("key","value");
 df.write().mode("overwrite").save(ParquetPath);
```